# Convert javascript string to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have string like this

```
    '10:00','13:00','12:00','15:00','08:00','12:00'
```

I need it in format like this

Array(3)

```
  Array[0] ['10:00', '13:00']
  Array[1] ['12:00', '15:00']
  Array[2] ['08:00', '12:00']
```

I tried with split method but without success.

Comment: "I tried with split method but without success." Please show your code.

Comment: This might be helpful https://gist.github.com/webinista/11240585

Comment: @kgbph You should *never* extend the prototypes of built-ins. E.g. never extend `Array.prototype`.

Comment: @str Why not? It's perfectly fine to extend prototypes if well documented. And of course you need to take care of conflicts. But if someone extends prototypes he/she should know what they do anyway.

Comment: @Akaino [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)

Comment: @str I know that. But it also states `Changing the behaviour of an object that will only be used by your own code is fine.` So I still don't see a problem if you know what you're doing. Not saying it's good practice.

Comment: @Akaino The problem is that not many people know what it implies and how it can break their code. And there are many cases where it even influenced the development of ECMAScript in a bad way. For example, `Array.prototype.includes` is called `includes` because `contains` was already used by many libraries and the committee feared the incompatibilities.

Answer (score 6):

You could replace single quotes with double quotes, add brackes and parse it as [JSON](https://json.org/) and get an array, which is the grouped by two elements.

```js
var string = "'10:00','13:00','12:00','15:00','08:00','12:00'",
    array = JSON
        .parse('[' + string.replace(/'/g, '"') + ']')
        .reduce((r, s, i) => r.concat([i % 2 ? r.pop().concat(s) : [s]]), []);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
var str = "'10:00','13:00','12:00','15:00','08:00','12:00'";
var oldArray = str.split(',');
var newArray = [];

while(oldArray.length){
    let start = 0;
    let end = 2;
    newArray.push(oldArray.slice(start, end));
    oldArray.splice(start, end);
 }
 
 console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.split(',')` to split into individual values, then group them based on their positions (result of integer division with 2).

I am using [groupBy](https://30secondsofcode.org/array#groupby) from **30 seconds of code** (disclaimer: I am one of the maintainers of the project/website) to group the elements based on the integer division with 2. Short explanation:

> Use `Array.map()` to map the values of an array to a function or property name. Use `Array.reduce()` to create an object, where the keys are produced from the mapped results.

The result is an object, but can be easily converted into an array using `Object.values()` as shown below:

```js
var data = "'10:00','13:00','12:00','15:00','08:00','12:00'";

const groupBy = (arr, fn) =>
  arr.map(typeof fn === 'function' ? fn : val => val[fn]).reduce((acc, val, i) => {
    acc[val] = (acc[val] || []).concat(arr[i]);
    return acc;
  }, {});

var arr = data.split(',');
arr = groupBy(arr, (v, i) => Math.floor(i / 2));
arr = Object.values(arr);

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
"'10:00','13:00','12:00','15:00','08:00','12:00'"
.replace(/'/g, '').replace(/(,[^,]*),/g,"$1;")
.split(';').map(itm => itm.split(','))
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you want to compare 2 values.
To do this you can make a for loop that reads the current value and the last value and compares the two.
If the last value is higher than current value, the splitting logic happens.

Either you add the current value to the last item (which is an array of strings) in the results array or you add a new array of strings at the end of the results array.

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution:

```
let S = "'10:00','13:00','12:00','15:00','08:00','12:00'";

let R = S.split(',');

let I = 0;

let A = new Array([],[],[]);

R.map((object, index) => {
    A[I][index % 2] = R[index];
    if (index % 2 == 1) I++;
});

console.log(A);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think use `JSON.parse` is better:

```js
var array = "'10:00','13:00','12:00','15:00','08:00','12:00'";

array = JSON.parse( '[' + array.replace(/'/g,'"') + ']' );

var array2 = [];
for(var i=0;i < array.length - 1; i++){
    array2.push([array[i], array[i+1]]);
}

console.log(array2);
```